# Scan function in Microsoft Acess?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to substring based on a space character in my text field, but I'm unable to do it successfully.

My field has two but sometimes three words all separated y a space. I'd like to be able to pull out the second or third word by matching on the space. The word are of variable length.

I have tried things like this, but without success.

```
select mid([genus],InStr([genus]," ")+1) AS species from <tablename>;
```

Any suggestions?
thank you.

Comment: So which do you want, the second or third word?  Do you just want the last word?  Do you want a column with the second word and a different column with the third word?  Do you want a single column that uses a random function to return either the second or third word?

Answer (score 2):

For the last word you can:

```
SELECT Mid(genus,1 + InStrRev(genus," ")) AS species
```

For the 2nd word if there are 2 or more;

```
SELECT mid(genus,InStr(genus," ")+1, instr(InStr(genus," "),genus, " ")-1)  AS species
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried the second option, but it returned #Error. I also tried the first option and it returned the first word, not the last??

Comment: For a field where there is *no* space it will fail, are there such? If so do you want "" or the single word?

Comment: There is a space in all entries as it includes genus and species. I'm trying to skip over the genus and extract the species name. I'm using Access 2007 - not sure if that makes a difference. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Odd if I add TABLE[genus], "aaa bbb" | "aaa bbb ccc" I get "bbb" from the query for both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```vb
Public Function Item(ByVal s As String, ByVal index As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal delimiter As String = " ") As String
    Dim i As Long, pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long

    If index < 1 Or index > Len(s) Then
        Item = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    s = s & delimiter
    pos2 = 1 - Len(delimiter)
    For i = 1 To index
        pos1 = pos2 + Len(delimiter)
        pos2 = InStr(pos1, s, delimiter, vbBinaryCompare)
        If pos2 = 0 Then
            Item = ""
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    Item = Mid$(s, pos1, pos2 - pos1)
End Function
```

Test

```vb
Item("asdas df 4354 sdf", 3)
```

yields

```vb
"4354"
```

In your select statement

```sql
SELECT
    Item(genus, 1) AS word1,
    Item(genus, 2) AS word2,
    Item(genus, 3) AS word3
FROM
    <tablename>;
```